# Why is adding site to an object doesn't seem to work in a save() override in the Django admin?

Tags: django, save

I have overrided the `save()` method of one of my model so it can inherit from the [sites object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/sites/) and tags from its parent.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    ret = models.Model.save(self, *args, **kwargs)

    if self.id:

        for site in self.parent.sites.all():
            self.sites.add(site.id)

        for tag in self.parent.tags_set.all():
            Tag.objects.add_tag(self, tag)
```

Using `ipdb`, I can see that `self.sites.all()` DOES return 4 sites at the end of the method, but strangely, once the request is finish, the same `self.sites.all()` does not return anything anymore.

I don't use transactions (at least explicitly), and I'm using Django 1.3 and Ubuntu 11.04

EDIT: found out that it works anywhere but in the admin. Doesn't the admin call save? If not, how can I hook to the object creation / update?

EDIT2: tested, and does call save. I have print statements to prove it. But it doesn't add the sites. It's a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this is a problem about adding programatically many to many relationships when saving a model if you use the Django admin.

Django save m2m relationships in the admin by calling 'clear' to wipe them out, then setting them again. It means that the form destroy any attached data (including your programatically attached) to the object then add the ones you entered in the admin.

It works outside the admin because we don't use the admin form that clear the m2m relationship.

The reason it works for tags in the admin is that the tagging application doesn't use m2m but emulate it by placing a TaggedItem object with a foreign key to a tag and to your model with a generic relation. Plus it's an inline field inclusion.

I tried a lot of things and finally had to look at the Django source code to realize that Django does not process admin forms in the usual way. What it does it:

1. call `ModelAdmin.save_form`: it calls `form.save` with `commit = False`, returning an unsaved instance and adding a `save_m2m` method to the form.
2. call `ModelAdmin.save_model` that actually calls the instance `save` method.
3. call `form.save_m2m`

Therefor:

- you can't override your `save` method since `save_m2m` is called after and clear the m2m relations.
- you can't override `save_model` for the same reason.
- you can't override `save_m2m` because it is added by monkey patch to the form model in `form.save`, erasing you own method definition.

I didn't find a clean solution, but something that works is:

Provide a form for the ModelAdmin class with a method to override `save_m2m` with your own method:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def set_m2m_method(self, update_tags_and_sites=True):

        alias = self.save_m2m

        def new_save_m2m(): # this is your new method 
            alias() # we need to call the original method as well
            self.instance.add_niche_sites_and_tags()

        self.save_m2m = new_save_m2m # we erase Django erasing :-)
```

Call this method in a `ModelAdmin.model_save` override:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = MyModelForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        form.set_m2m_method()
```

This cause the following:

1. Django calls `save_model`, replacing its monkey patch by yours
2. django calls our `form.save_m2m` that first call its old method that clears relations, then attach the m2m to the object.

I'm completely open to any better way to do this as this is twisted and plain ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem seems to be reserved to admin, I tried to add some logic to do this in the `ModelAdmin`'s `save_model` method, but it doesn't seem to help at all:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        for site in Site.objects.all():
            obj.sites.add(site.id)
        print obj.sites.all()
```

Oddly `print obj.sites.all()` does list all the sites, however, they don't stay saved. Some sort of M2M issue perhaps?

Comment: Either way should work, however, this is how I call super methods too.

Comment: Super won't change anything as sites relation are outside the object itself. Plus, I can't put the custom logic at the top of the save method since I need reference to a saved object at object creation to attach a anything on it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it would help (unless you had something really crazy going on), but I still think that should be the preferred approach (but I guess it's a matter of taste). If you share the more of the code for your model(s) (how do you derive `parent`?) it might reveal something. Just tested using `Site.objects.all()` to automatically add all sites for an instance in `save` and it worked fine. So maybe there is something weird with your `parent`?

Comment: Found out it's related to the django admin. Updated the question.

Comment: Peculiar, I'll try to verify at least.

Comment: Yeah, I am definitely having the same issue. I've tried overriding `save_model` on the `ModelAdmin` (and it does indeed add the sites) but they disappear after the save!

Comment: Thanks for verifying. I'm going to ask their mailing list or IRC since I can be sure it's not an isolated case. If I get a solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: Got the answer on IRC #django

Comment: Posted the full solution. At least you'll be warned about this :-)