# Django - How to compare pre / post save state of a model including all relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to maintain a few sets in redis that track models in django

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    carriers = models.ManyToManyField(Carrier)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Campaign)
def adserver_clear_cache(sender, **kwargs):
    campaign = kwargs['instance']
    for con in campaign.countries.all():
        r.srem("con:" + str(con.id), campaign.id)
    for car in campaign.carriers.all():
        r.srem("car:" + str(car.id), campaign.id)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Campaign)
def adserver_save_cache(sender, **kwargs):
    campaign = kwargs['instance']
    for con in campaign.countries.all():
        r.sadd("con:" + str(con.id), campaign.id)
    for car in campaign.carriers.all():
        r.sadd("car:" + str(car.id), campaign.id)
```

The issue is, the campaign is fully saved, before each of the carriers, campaigns and such are saved. So I am getting the same data in pre + post_save. Is there a way to call a function when everything, including relations are finished saving?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the m2m relationship is saved *after* your model is saved, in other words "post_save() is still too early" for what you're after.

You can either use the m2m_changed signal as jpic points out, or use Django 1.4's new "save_related" - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related which closed ticket 16115 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16115

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8462541/640759

Answer (score 0):

**ManyToManyField is special**. It does not represent in the database by a column of its model's table. In fact, **a ManyToManyField represents as another table** that links the models at both sides of the n:m relation.

It does not make sense to emit a model signal such as post_save for an arbitrary side of the n:m relation. **When a ManyToManyField changes, [m2m_changed signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) is emited**:

> Sent when a ManyToManyField is changed on a model instance. Strictly speaking, this is not a model signal since it is sent by the ManyToManyField, but since it complements the pre_save/post_save and pre_delete/post_delete when it comes to tracking changes to models, it is included here.

Comment: I tried this, with similar results. pre_add and pre_remove seem to get the same thing... Also I may have 10+ relations with campaign and I am hoping to do all of the redis updating in one place.

Comment: Can you bind the m2m_changed signal like you did with pre_save and pre_delete ?