# Manipulate m2m records in django admin's save_model method

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models,

```
class Course(models.Model):
    #bunch of fields
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

class Student(models.Model):
    #bunch of fields
```

Now, instead of using the "regular" m2m widget in the Course admin screen, I added a file upload field in CourseAdminForm, to upload a text file with student IDs. I process the file in CourseAdmin.save_model method, iterating over a list of students like

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    #some other stuff
    #...
    obj.save()

    #obtain student_ids from uploaded file
    #...        
    for id in student_ids:
        s = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
        course.students.add(s)
    obj.save() #not sure this second one is needed
```

As it turns out, this doesn't work: **the m2m relations are not saved**. From what I've read, I understand this is because the whole save_model method happens within a transaction and after it is committed, the m2m relations are CLEARED and saved again, IF they come from a m2m widget. My problem thus is that I need to manipulate those relation by hand, and I just couldn't find a way (or a place) to do it.

The question thus is: how could I achieve the intended result of programmatically adding those m2m relations?

Answer (score 1):

You can either connect to the m2m_changed signal https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed, or use Django 1.4's new "save_related" - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related which closed ticket 16115 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16115

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8462541/640759